# Python pandas: ParserError: multi-char delimiter is used

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I'm trying to load a rather large file as a pandas dataframe. It is tab seperated, so I used

```
data = pd.read_csv("20200729", sep = '/t')
```

and python returned
ParserError: Expected 1 fields in line 122, saw 3. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

my file structure is

```
#tax_id GeneID  Symbol  LocusTag        Synonyms        dbXrefs chromosome      map_location    description     type_of_gene    Symbol_from_nomenclature_authority      Full_name_from_nomenclature_authority   Nomenclature_status       Other_designations      Modification_date       Feature_type
7       5692769 NEWENTRY        -       -       -       -       -       Record to support submission of GeneRIFs for a gene not in Gene (Azotirhizobium caulinodans.  Use when strain, subtype, isolate, etc. is unspecified, or when different from all specified ones in Gene.).        other   -       -       -       -       20190202        -
9       1246500 repA1   pLeuDn_01       -       -       -       -       putative replication-associated protein protein-coding  -       -       -       -       20180129        -
```

and it looks like line 122 (NEWENTRY) has a really long description under the description column. I have about 70 different versions of this file and i need to be able to parse them without dealing with that error, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try use an option `error_bad_lines=False`.

```
data = pd.read_csv("20200729", sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False)
```

**Check the full name of the file.** Maybe the file fullname is `20200729.csv` and you are missing the extensions **.csv**

Comment: Thank you. I'm ashamed, but the issue was i typed /t instead of \t for the tab delimiter. Feeling real dumb right now

Comment: Ops, i didn't saw that. great that worked :D